# Flexible table ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Is the following possible and if so how do I change my HTML to allow it?

I have the following model;

```
prospect = [{"name":"jamie",
             "phones": [{
                         "type":"home",
                         "number":"01275"},
                        {
                         "type":"mobile",
                         "number":"0788"}]},
            {"name":"peter",
             "phones": [{
                         "type":"mobile",
                         "number":"07852"}]}
           ]
```

and I would like to display - in an angularjs table  - like this

```
name  home  mobile
jamie 01275 0788
peter       07852
```

My current HTML

```
<table>
        <tbody ng-repeat='person in prospect'>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th ng-repeat="phone in person.phones">{{phone.type}}</th>
        <tr>
        <td>
        {{person.name}}
        </td>
            <td ng-repeat='phone in person.phones'>
                {{phone.number}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

produces

```
Name    home    mobile
jamie    01275   0788
Name    mobile
peter    07852
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaydubyasee/D7f2k/

Comment: Is the model fixed? I mean are the phone types ever going to be home and mobile, or do you have to account for multiple phone types as well as multiple numbers of the same type?

Comment: The model at the moment is such that there will be a maximum of 1 home number and 1 mobile number per person. However I would like, if possible, to retain the flexibility of multiple type and multiple numbers.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in html, without modifying your json, I'd first add an array that indicates what type of phone goes into each column:

```
$scope.types= ["home","mobile"];
```

Then use it in the header:

```
<th ng-repeat="type in types">{{type}}</th>
```

Then to print out the phone numbers we iterate over each phone within each column, using [`ngIf`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf) to conditionally show any phones that match that column's type:

```
<td ng-repeat='type in types'>
    <span ng-repeat='pphone in person.phones' ng-if="pphone.type == type">
       {{pphone.number}}
    </span>           
</td>
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D7f2k/7/)

A variation would be to replace the nested `ngRepeat`s with a custom directive that displays the correct phone for the given column and row.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that for the second entry peter doesn't have a 'home' number. The 'mobile' number is appearing under the 'home' heading.

Comment: There's a problem in this solution. The mobile number for the second person is showing up in "home" column.

Comment: @KayakDave I agree with your solution. I think the JSON structure does not allow other way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will like this solution :)

I did you this dependency

```
bower install angular
bower install ng-tasty
bower install bootstrap
```

And here the full solution

```
  <div tasty-table bind-resource="resource">
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
      <thead tasty-thead></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
          <td ng-bind="row.name"></td>
          <td ng-bind="row.phones | filterTypeColumn:'home'"></td>
          <td ng-bind="row.phones | filterTypeColumn:'mobile'"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/ng-tasty/ng-tasty-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('stackOverflowAnswer', ['ngTasty'])
    .filter('filterTypeColumn', function() {
      return function (input, typeColumn) {
        var phoneNumber;
        input.forEach(function (phone) {
          if (phone.type === typeColumn) {
            phoneNumber = phone.number;
          }
        })
        return phoneNumber;
      };
    })
    .controller('StackOverflowController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.resource = {
        "header": [
          { "name": "Name" },
          { "home": "Home" },
          { "mobile": "Mobile" }
        ],
        "rows": [
          { 
            "name":"jamie",
            "phones": [
              { "type":"home","number":"01275" },
              { "type":"mobile", "number":"0788"}
            ]
          },
          {
            "name":"peter",
            "phones": [
              { "type":"mobile","number":"07852"}
            ]
          }
        ]
      };
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want know more about ngTasty you can find all the doc here http://zizzamia.com/ng-tasty/directive/table .
For your specific case, the solution was make a custom filter.

Ciao